# not getting any data from the listed triggers in zabbix

Tags: triggers, zabbix

I am little confuse in  zabbix triggers expresion, right now i am triggering an application count `netstat -anp | grep 1433 |wc -l` but I am getting no data from these trigger, can any one please help?

thanks in advance
**item** `proc.num[1433]` **trigger** `{hostname:proc.num[1433].last()}>1500`

Comment: The command `netstat` lists connections, while the key `proc.num[<name>,<user>,<state>,<cmdline>,<zone>]` lists processes. Which one are you looking for, connections or processes?

Comment: hi, thanks for reply i am looking for the connections count on port 1433

Comment: when i execute  netstat -anp | grep 1433 |wc -l command i will show me the number of connections on port 1433

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix Agent doesn't have any key to count TCP/UDP connections. To collect the result of `netstat` you need a custom script, through [user parameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/userparameters). Also note that `grep -c` prints the number of lines, for example:

To count established connections on port 443:

```
netstat -an | egrep -c ":443 *ESTABLISHED"
```

Comment: I am using userparameter
Option: UserParameter=database.user.count,netstat -anp | grep 1433 | wc -l

Comment: netstat -an | egrep -c ":1433 *ESTABLISHED" this command is not giving any output

Comment: Weird. I tested it on grep (GNU grep) 2.20, GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2), CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 ... can you confirm 1443 is the port, not the pid?

Comment: 1433 is a port for Database server, netstat -anp | grep 1433 | wc -l  this command gives me the no of connection on this port right now the total no connection is 11621